# how to solve "Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Bad credentials"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to work with OAuth2. but I have problem. I can't access token.
this is my code

model.entity.user:

```
package com.example.oauth2.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "users")
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar2(20)")
    private String username;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar2(20)")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk")
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User(String username, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

model.entity.Role:

```
package com.example.oauth2.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "roles")
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

model.repository.UserDA:

```
import com.example.oauth2.model.entity.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDA {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public void save(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }


    public User findById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }


    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select entity from users entity");
        //query.setParameter("n",username);
        List<User> users = query.getResultList();
        User u=null;
        for (User user : users) {
            if (user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
               u = user;
               break;
            }
        }
        return u;
    }

}
```

model.service.UserDetailImpl:

```
package com.example.oauth2.model.service;

import com.example.oauth2.model.entity.Role;
import com.example.oauth2.model.entity.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


public class UserDetailImpl implements UserDetails {


    private String password;
    private String username;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserDetailImpl(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorities = translate(user.getRoles());
    }


    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate(List<Role> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role : roles) {
            String roleName = role.getName().toUpperCase();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName));
        }

        return authorities;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

controller.HomeController:

```
package com.example.oauth2.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "Home";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/private")
    public String privatem() {
        return "private";
    }

}
```

config.AuthorizationServerConfig:

```
package com.example.oauth2.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","USER")
                .scopes("read","write","trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1000)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"));
    }


   @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

config.ResourseServerConfig:

```
package com.example.oauth2.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourseServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {




    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/private").authenticated();
    }
}
```

config.WebSecurityConfig:

```
package com.example.oauth2.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("2222222222222222222");
        auth
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

this is my request:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=user
```

and Authorization :

`username: my-trusted-client
password: secret`

and this is my warning:

`2019-11-14 18:32:17.229  WARN 14920 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2019-11-14 18:32:17.231  WARN 14920 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Bad credentials`

can you help me please;
I think very much about this but I can't solve it;

Answer (score 0):

First, you already are setting the enconder in your `configureGlobal` method so I think you don't need to encode your password in your `configure` method so try to change the follow:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","USER")
            .scopes("read","write","trust")
            .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1000)
            .secret("secret"); // remove this encode
}
```

And then sent you password encrypted to the application:

As you are using BCrypt add the `{bcrypt}` prefix.
Do this in a method just to get the password you must sent:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String password = "{bcrypt}" + passwordEncoder.encode("secret");
}
```

Then sent this password in you request:

```
username: my-trusted-client
password: password-generated-by-crypt
```